# Estimating error when calculating $\pi^2$ with $8 + \frac{8}{3^2} + \frac{8}{5^2} + \frac{8}{7^2} + \cdots$

Tags: approximation, pi

While answering a CodeReview question ([Approximating constant $\pi^2$ to within error](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188920/approximating-constant-%CF%80%C2%B2-to-within-error)), I noticed that when calculating the sum 
$$8 + \dfrac{8}{3^2} + \dfrac{8}{5^2} + \dfrac{8}{7^2} + \dfrac{8}{9^2} + \cdots $$

and stopping at the smallest term larger than $\varepsilon$, the difference to $\pi^2$ seems very close to $\sqrt{2\varepsilon}$.

With $$n = \left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{\frac{8}{\varepsilon}} - 1}{2} \right\rfloor,$$

it looks like:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{8}{(2i+1)^2} \approx \pi^2 - \sqrt{2\varepsilon}.$$

For [example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/188956/139491), with $\varepsilon = 10^{-10}$:

$n = 141421$

$\sum = 9.86959025 \dots$

$\pi^2 - \sum \approx 1.4142170*10^{-5}$

$(\pi^2 - \sum)^2 \approx 2.0000099*10^{-10} \approx 2\varepsilon$

I don't think it's a coincidence, but I don't know where to begin to link

$$\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{8}{(2i+1)^2}$$ to $\sqrt{2\varepsilon}$.

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(8%2F(2*i%2B1)**2,%20i,%20n%2B1,%20infinity)) expresses this sum in terms of a [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) but I don't know anything about it.

Is the approximation correct? Is there any simple way to prove it?

Comment: The usual method of estimating the error in such series is the Euler-Maclaurin formula.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

One has
$${2\over (2k+1)^2}<{1\over 2k}-{1\over 2k+2}\ ,$$
and therefore (teleskoping sum!)
$$0<\sum_{k=n}^\infty{2\over(2k+1)^2}<{1\over 2n}\ ,$$
or
$$0<\sum_{k=n}^\infty{8\over(2k+1)^2}<{2\over n}\ .$$
Maybe this will bring you over the top.

Comment: Thanks  a lot. If I understand it correctly, we still need another inequality to prove that the sum isn't too far from $\frac{2}{n}$, right?

Comment: Applying the same logic with ${1\over 2k+1}-{1\over 2k+3} < {2\over (2k+1)^2}$, we obtain $\frac{2}{n+1} < \sum < \frac{2}{n}$, right? That would be a pretty good approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Recall from calculus the integral test:

> $$\displaystyle\sum a(n)\text{ converges if and only if }\int a(x)\text{ converges}$$ where the sequence $a(n)=a_n>0$ and $a_n$ is decreasing, and the function $a(x)$ is continuous.

From the proof of this statement, we can deduce the inequality: if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=L$, then $$\left|L-\sum_{i=0}^n a_n\right|\leq\int_{n}^\infty a(x)\,dx,$$(see [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralTest.aspx) for help with providing visual intuition as to why the inequality is true) where the notation $a(x)$ is used to represent $a_n$ with the $n$ replaced by $x$. Thus, performing the necessary calculations, we find

\begin{align*}
\int_{n}^\infty\frac{8}{(2x+1)^2}\,dx&=\frac{4}{2n+1}\\
&\leq\frac{4}{\sqrt{\frac{8}\varepsilon}-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}}-\frac14}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2\varepsilon}}{1-\frac{\sqrt{2\varepsilon}}{4}}\\
&\approx \sqrt{2\varepsilon},\end{align*}
where I've taken $$n=\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{\frac{8}{\varepsilon}}-1}{2}\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: This looks good, thanks. I'll try to do it again on a piece of paper and come back to comment/accept.

Comment: Thanks, @EricDuminil. There was one place I had something like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}}+1}$ where I had to use some algebra to simplify (hence I didn't want to type it, at least, not yet haha).

Comment: First, the integral test has _hypotheses_ that you need to mention. And, although the estimate you give for the error is correct (under the same hypotheses!), I don't see how we can deduce that error estimate from the integral test itself. How does that go?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I suppose it is more from the proof of the integral test than the integral test itself, but the idea is that the sequence/function is positive and decreasing, so we can set it up so the integral is an overestimate (if you prefer to think in terms of Riemann sums, it is like using right endpoints for the estimate).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: You're right about the test having hypotheses that I ought to mention. I knew I wouldn't have much time when I submitted the answer. At any rate, I'm at fault for not being explicit enough. I have about an hour now, so I'll provide more explanations. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: I already made another suggestion: Explain _how_ we can deduce that inequality from the theorem! I simply don't believe it. (Of course the inequality follows from the proof of the theorem...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Yes, of course; I meant suggestions besides those already provided by you. I'm working on edits now.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I think I've integrated the changes you've suggested.

Comment: Same comment as for the other answer : this inequality proves that the partial sum is at most $\sqrt{2\varepsilon}$ away from $L$, right? Could it be proven that the partial sum isn't far away from $L - \sqrt{2\varepsilon}$?

Comment: @EricDuminil: Since I've got absolute values around $L-\sum a_n$, this means $$L-\sqrt{2\varepsilon}\leq\sum a_n\leq L+\sqrt{2\varepsilon}.$$ Here, the inequalities really mean "approximately" and, in fact, since the partial sums are increasing, the upper bound is $L$ itself. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Clayton: Sorry to bother you again, but I'm afraid it doesn't answer the question completely. This inequality shows that $\sum a_n$ is between $L-\sqrt{2\varepsilon}$ and $L$. I'd like to show that it's much closer to $L-\sqrt{2\varepsilon}$ than to $L$. Something like $\left|L - (\sum a_n + \sqrt{2\varepsilon})\right| \lt f(\varepsilon)$ . Does that make sense?

Comment: @EricDuminil: Yes, I understand better now. I'll consider it, but I don't have time to write anything down right now.